# Distribution of the minimum of a pair of random observations

Tags: estimation, sampling, paired-data

A test results interpretation question, which I think boils down to this: what is the distribution of the minima of pairs of values sampled at random from a known distribution (say, Gaussian) and can the parameters of the latter be estimated knowing or estimating the parameters of the former?

Suppose that one wants to measure the breaking strength of some type of rope, by pulling it to failure, but with a twist: the rope is to be attached to the test rig with a particular knot.  The idea is that the knot weakens the rope and that the rope will break at the knot at some lower range of tensions than without it.

If one keeps testing samples of the rope with the knot on one end, eventually some outline of the distribution of the rope+knot breaking strength will emerge and predictive inferences may be attempted.

But what happens if each test uses a length of rope with two knots, one at each end?  One can only record the breaking strength of the weaker of the two (one knot breaks first which ends the test).

I imagine that the distribution of values in such dual-knot tests will be biased low and be less scattered?  But if this is the only data available, can one try to estimate back from it what the actual distribution of breaking strength of all the knots may have been?

It may not be quite true in practice - as the rope/knots breaking strengths tend to be positively skewed resembling Log-Normal PDF, and sometimes seem to be even multimodal - but maybe assuming that the original distribution was Normal or at least symmetric (which probably happens often enough) could make such transformation back to the underlying distribution easier?

Comment: You may wish to read into [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) more if you have not already. See [*Probability of Min of X Greater than Max of Y*](https://galenseilis.github.io/posts/dist-min-greater-than-max/) as a related example.

Answer (score 0):

If the pairs are sampled from the same distribution, I think this is pretty straightforward, although I don't have time to flesh out the reasoning.
Here's an example for the Gaussian case.

```r
generate_data = function(n=1000, mu, sigma){
  x1 = rnorm(n, mu, sigma)
  x2 = rnorm(n, mu, sigma)
  ifelse(x1 < x2, x1, x2)
}
x = generate_data(10000, mu = 10, sigma = 2)
hist(x)
```

[image]

```r
log_likelihood = function(x, mu, sigma){
  # Likelihood of x1 taking on this value
  log_lik_x1 = dnorm(x, mu, sigma, log = T)
  # Probability that x2 exceeds this value
  log_lik_x2_is_higher = pnorm(x, mu, sigma, log.p = T, lower.tail = F)
  # Using sum here, because these are log values
  log_lik_x1 + log_lik_x2_is_higher
}

f = function(pars){
  -1 * sum(log_likelihood(x, pars[1], pars[2]))
}
initial_guess = c(2, 2)
optim(initial_guess, f)
#> Warning in dnorm(x, mu, sigma, log = T): NaNs produced
#> Warning in pnorm(x, mu, sigma, log.p = T, lower.tail = F): NaNs produced
#> $par
#> [1] 9.988886 2.000579
#> 
#> $value
#> [1] 26124.43
#> 
#> $counts
#> function gradient 
#>       91       NA 
#> 
#> $convergence
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $message
#> NULL
```

Comment: Many thanks for this - I think I almost understand it.  Such Monte Carlo solution should be applicable to any distribution, not just Gaussian, I think.  I have added as an answer what seems to be an acceptable analytical solution/estimate which should work for minima of pairs from the same Gaussian distribution.

Comment: This isn't a Monte Carlo simulation, it's maximum-likelihood estimation. The sample is just to generate test data.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this paper](https://www.gwern.net/docs/conscientiousness/2008-nadarajah.pdf).  If equations 11 and 12 are simplified for pairs of values sampled from a single Gaussian distribution with parameters mu1 and sigma1, then the estimated parameters of the resulting distribution of minima of those pairs (mu2 and sigma2, also Gaussian or close to it) can be linked as follows, I believe:

To estimate the parameters of the original distribution:

**mu1 = mu2 + 0.683*sigma2**

**sigma1 = 1.212*sigma2**

To estimate the parameters of the distribution of pairs' minima:

**mu2 = mu1 - 0.564*sigma1**

**sigma2 = sqrt(mu1^2 + sigma1^2 - 1.129*mu1*sigma1 - mu2^2)**

While I posted it as an 'answer', it would be great if this could be confirmed by someone else.  I think it's right and it seems to agree with a few Monte Carlo runs I tried.

p.s. I'm sorry for not using MathJax - I'm not sure how yet...